# C++ template class friend with all type

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I have a Vector class and I overload the operator*

I would like to be able to multiply a Vector of float with a Vector of int.

I have the following code but when I compile him, I have an error because I don't have access to private fields.

```cpp
template <class T>
class Vecteur
{
    template <class U> friend class Vecteur;

private:
    int m_dimensions;
    T *m_values;
}

template<class T1, class T2>
T1 operator*(const Vecteur<T1> &v1, const Vecteur<T2> &v2)
{
    assert(v1.m_dimensions == v2.m_dimensions);
    T res = T();
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.m_dimensions; i++)
    {
        res += v1.m_values[i] * v2.m_values[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

I also tried this but I can access to private fields of v1 but not to the private fields of v2

```cpp
template <class T>
class Vecteur
{
private:
    int m_dimensions;
    T *m_values;

    template<class T2>
    friend T operator*(const Vecteur<T> &v1, const Vecteur<T2> &v2)
    {
        assert(v1.m_dimensions == v2.m_dimensions);
        T res = T();
        for (int i = 0; i < v1.m_dimensions; i++)
        {
            res += v1.m_values[i] * v2.m_values[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `template <class U> friend class Vecteur;` to do?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, sure, but `operator*` is not - and it is a free-standing function in this example.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I know what it means.  I'm asking the OP what their intention was.

Comment: Originaly, my code is the second.
I see the first in other posts.
I would like to obtain an operator* who can acces to private fields of Vecteur<int> and Vecteur<float>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version declares one specialization of `Vecteur` a friend of another. This doesn't help your operator `*`, since this is still not a friend and can't access private members.

Add proper friend declaration for template overload in your `Vecteur` (and you do not need to friend the specialization):

```
template<class T>
class Vectuer {
//...
template<class T1, class T2> std::common_type_t<T1, T2>
friend operator*(const Vecteur<T1>& , const Vectuer<T2>& );
//...
};

// And than a definition after the declaration
```

Alternatively, you can friend the specialization, and add `operator*` as a member, but I do not like this, since such overloaded operators are more cleanly implemented as freestanding functions.

Comment: Thank you very much it works but I'm not sure to understand the std::common_type_t<T1, T2>
I have tried with T1 in place of this and I have the same result

Comment: Imagine you are multiplying vector of ints by vector of floats. With just T1, you will end up with integer result (while float would be a desired outcome)

Comment: It not works for me. With your std::common_type_t<T1, T2> I also obtain a vector of ints if I multiply a vector of ints with a vector of floats

Comment: My bad it's work, I just missed to replace T1 with std::common_type_t<T1, T2> in the code of the function

Comment: It's ok look my previous message.

Comment: @SteevenTronet, Ok I see. Removing my comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the urge to declare a function or a class a friend of a class, take moment to look at your design and ask yourself whether that is absolutely necessary.

In the case of the posted code, instead of trying to solve the problem associated with granting `friend`-ship to the `operator*` function, provide accessor functions to the data of the class and get rid of the need for granting `friend`-ship altogether.

```
template <class T>
class Vecteur
{
   public:

      int getDimensions() const { return m_dimensions; };
      T& operator[](std::size_t i) { return m_values[i]; };
      T const& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return m_values[i]; };

   private:
    int m_dimensions;
    T *m_values;
};

// Does not require to be a friend of the class.
template<class T1, class T2>
typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type operator*(const Vecteur<T1> &v1, const Vecteur<T2> &v2)
{
    assert(v1.getDimensions() == v2.getDimensions());

    typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type res{};
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.getDimensions(); i++)
    {
        res += v1[i] * v2[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know this but I just need to work with friend to improve my knowledge

Comment: I disagree. There is no point in giving accessors to otherwise internal members. You are now exposing inner details to outside world, and might just as well make the member public. Friendship for standalone functions, which are logically a part of interface (and contract) is a much better approach.

Comment: @SergeyA, we, obviously, have different approaches to software development.

Comment: +1 completely agree: a vector (in the physical/mathemathical sense) should give public constant access to its components.